# Add column to Interactive pd.DataFrame

Tags: pandas, panel

I'm having trouble to understand how to deal with pandas DataFrame once it is interactive.
Also I can't find any helpful sources to find out what options an interactive DataFrame is providing.

Currently I am stuck trying to add a column to an interactive Dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import hvplot.pandas
import holoviews as hv
import panel as pn

dictionary = {'A':[12,13,14,15],
              'B':[17,18,19,20],
              'C':[35,36,37,38],
              'D':[45,46,47,48]}

index = pd.to_datetime(['2017-06-08', '2017-06-09', '2017-06-10', '2017-06-11'])

df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary, index=index)

dfi = df.interactive()
```

I added a panel-Date slider to play around with the DataFrame:

```
date_slider = pn.widgets.DateRangeSlider(name='Date',start=df.index.min(),end=df.index.max())

slider_df = dfi[
        (dfi.index >= date_slider.param.value_start) &
        (dfi.index <= date_slider.param.value_end)].sum()
```

The output I want to discuss looks like this: [Interactive DataFrame with Date-Slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GY5to.png)

I have the sum of all selected values in an extra column.

How can I rename the column to "sum"? How can I add another column for .mean()?

Comment: I'm sorry, I think it has something to do with the imports!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

```
slider_df = dfi[
        (dfi.index >= date_slider.param.value_start) &
        (dfi.index <= date_slider.param.value_end)].agg(['sum','mean'])
```

which will result in

[image]

or

```
slider_df = dfi[
        (dfi.index >= date_slider.param.value_start) &
        (dfi.index <= date_slider.param.value_end)].agg(['sum','mean']).T
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I was asking for! Thank you very much! It sometimes takes a very long time for jupyter to give an output, any ideas why? Also could you please recommend some sources for me to gather more information about methods like .agg ?

Comment: Glad it helped!! For the documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html . As for the latency in returning output, there can be many reasons due to your versions of python, pandas, or other packages, if you're running other things in the background that allocate memory. The size of the dataframe is one other issue that might create problems. My advice is for you to time each step in you code and see what is taking time.